# Quill - how to use modules?

Tags: javascript, module, quill

I'd like to use some Quill modules for my own purposes, for example I'd like to use image uploader.

https://github.com/quilljs/quill/blob/9a77567fe356d384074df7479c33ceac509d9351/modules/uploader.js

I'v got access to the quill instance after initialising it:

```
let quillContainerSelector = '.quill-container';

let quill = new Quill(quillContainerSelector, {
  modules: {
    toolbar: toolbarOptions
  },
  theme: 'snow',
});
```

How can I call **upload** function from *Uploader* module ?

Answer (score 2):

Create a module which you want use and import to the file where you creating the quill Editor. And before the initiating the quill just register the module you want to use.

Here, I'm using quill in react. Just look into this example you will get an idea.

```
import Quill from 'quill'
import ReactQuill,{Quill} from 'react-quill';
import MarkdownShortcuts from 'markdownShortCuts';
Quill.register('modules/markdownShortcuts',MarkdownShortcuts)
class Editor extends Component{
   constructor (props) {
     super(props)
     this.state = { editorHtml: '', }
    }
   modules = {
      markdownShortcuts:{}, 
  }
 render () {
return (
    <ReactQuill 
      modules={this.modules}
      value={this.state.editorHtml}
      placeholder={this.props.placeholder}
     />
 )
  }
}
```

Try like this while registering it will work.

Comment: what is markdownShortCuts? Where I can found it? Is there module dev documentation? Is there oss modules ecosystem?

Comment: https://github.com/patleeman/quill-markdown-shortcuts Here, you can find the documentation about markdownshortcuts plugin. And to see list of supported you can go to this url https://github.com/quilljs/awesome-quill.